Robust estimation of standard deviation using relatively small sample taken from a Gaussian distribution
I'm sure this question was asked before, but I don't seem to be able to find a convincing answer.
If there is a relatively small set (say 3<n<20) of observations of a quantity that is assumed to have a Gaussian distribution and the objective is to estimate the standard deviation of this distribution what would be a more robust approach?

use the standard formula for sample SD?
estimate the SD from the first and second quartile?

The second approach seems to be less reliant on extreme observations, but doesn't it underestimate the population SD?
I found a nice paper on the second approach but the idea behind it is to estimate SD when only the 5-number summary is available and the individual observations in the sample are not known.  I have access to all the individual observations as well.
https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-135
p.s. I want to add that the the practical application of this question is to estimate the variability of the systolic blood pressure measurements assuming that there is no drift during the multiple measurements of it, and that it is assumed the measurements are subject to normally distributed random noise with a constant SD.   There is no way of knowing whether the measurements in the sample from which the SD is to be estimated are contaminated with some outliers.  The SD estimated from the IQR is nearly always somewhat smaller than the SD estimated by the regular (n-1) formula.  I don't know what that indicates if anything.  Thank you.
p.s.s. I just found this paper that I think sheds some light on my question:  https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/48279/1978-1.pdf?sequence=1 In this paper T5 is the SD estimator based on IQR that I wanted to use.

Why use the SD at all? There are many alternatives. You mention IQR and 5 number summary. The disadvantage (if it is one) of those are that they are not single numbers. But there is median absolute deviation (MAD) and the trimmed SD, both of which are robust to outliers.

The idea is that I would like to estimate the uncertainty of future readings.  Assuming that the instrument doesn't drift with time, has little bias, and that the uncertainty (spread) of measurements taken close to each other is random and not proportional to the value being measured, and follows some semi-well-behaved distribution (perhaps symmetric, maybe Gaussian), I would like to spend time to estimate the extent of this spread and then assume it applies to future measurements if that makes sense.  For that, I assume a Gaussian spread but need a realistic SD to apply it.
